# Change $home for tomcat only?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I have two instances of tomcat that run under the same user in a test/dev environment. In each instance there is an application that writes configuration data to the same directory in the $home of the user that runs tomcat.

I'd like to set one instance of tomcat so that it thinks $home is somewhere else. Is this possible? If I do export home=foo/bar when I run one instance, will that affect the other instance?

Obviously I know that I can run each instance as a different user, I do not want to do that in this case.

Comment: If you start tomcat from a shell,  you can do export home=... in this shell before you start tomcat. home will be set for this shell only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a file "setenv.sh" for both instances

{TOMCAT1_BASE_DIR}/bin/setenv.sh:

```
export home=/foo/bar1
```

{TOMCAT2_BASE_DIR}/bin/setenv.sh:

```
export home=/foo/bar2
```

On startup tomcat will load environment variables defined in setenv.sh

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite a variable for a specified command without exporting it this way:

```
HOME=/home/user command.sh
```

The `HOME` variable will be changed for `command.sh` but will still be your usual home everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `{TOMCAT_INSTANCE}/bin/setenv.sh` to set all required environment variables per instance.